# ionic 2 angular 2 distribute binding records in two columns

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angular2-directives

I'm struggling with a simple action, I need to distribute some logos binded from firebase2 listobservable in two columns. I have a reference number, call order,  its a sequential number so I can know which is odd and which pair, but how can I leave one odd and one pair in the same row. This is my Idea of  "Binding Code" :

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row *ngFor="let hotel of hotels | async">
  <ion-col col-6 *ngIf="hotel.orden%2 == 1" (click)="itemTapped(hotel.$key)">
    <img src="{{hotel.logo}}" >
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6 *ngIf="hotel.orden%2 == 0" (click)="itemTapped(hotel.$key)">
     <img src="{{hotel.logo}}" >
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

In the collection "hotels", I have two elements: order and logo (logo is an image path).

Can anybody give me a hint please, I have been here for some ours .
Thanks in advance!

This is the Goal :

[image: this is the idea]

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-container to group elements every 2 steps like so :

[EDIT] : make sure hotels is of type any[]

```
<ion-grid *ngIf="hotels">
  <ion-row *ngFor="let hotel of hotels | async;let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="hotel.orden%2 == 0">
      <ion-col col-6 >
        <img src="{{hotel.logo}}" (click)="itemTapped(hotel.$key)">
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <img *ngIf="hotels.length - 1 > i && hotels[i+1].orden % 2 === 1"
              (click)="itemTapped(hotels[i+1].$key)"
              src="{{hotels[i+1].logo}}">
      </ion-col>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Assuming here that the first element is always even. if not then the first element will be dismissed. But I'm sure you can work something out from this point!

Comment: Hi Mehdi, thank you for your comments, its a nice idea, but I'm having problems using {{hotels[i+1].logo}}, I'm receiving this error message: "ERROR TypeError: co.hotels[v.context.index] is undefined", Do you think is a syntax error?

Comment: I don't know what your ts code looks like, but one guess i can make is that the error is caused by the fact that hotels is an Observable. I tested this code with the difference that hotels is an array of hotels that I build once the response comes back in the subscribe function. Try that!

Comment: Hi Mehdi, yes hotels is a Firebase List Observable -> this.hotels = db.list('hoteles/', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'orden',
        }

      });  and I tried to make a Subscription as you recomend me -> this.hotels = db.list('/hoteles/', { preserveSnapshot: true });
        this.hotels.subscribe(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
          });

      }); but I'm still having the same error message ; TypeError: co.hotels[v.context.index] is undefined

Comment: In your example, hotels is still an Observable. Try to store the actual array in hotels when it comes back. As a result, make sure you don't try to consume hotels until it exists. I have edited my response to reflect that